# Strange Database problem! PHP MySQL Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysql-num-rows

I am experiencing a strange problem with a simple query that returned the number of rows in a table.

This was always working fine and correct.

However! Yesterday I added a new function to my website that updates a column in existing rows in my table. This function called **add_file()**

Now my website is giving a wrong value of what it should be:

Currently there are **76** rows in my table called "procedure" viewed from phpMyadmin and SQLyog.

However in my website it is saying there are **70**.

> Machines DO NOT LIE, so this is most likely my doing

I have a hunch that  my function called **add_file()** is to blame.

What this function does is update the "edocument" column in my procedure table if a user uploads a file corresponding to that record. So that the system knows what that file is called and can construct a url for it.

```
        public function add_filename($file)
        {

            //This is the extension of the file retrieved from an array
            $extension = $file['upload_data']['file_ext'];


            //variable for updating row which is constructed from Username+Filename+Extension
            $filename = array
            (
                'edocument' => ($this->session->userdata('name').$this->input->post('record_id')).$extension
            );

            //find row that matches the row just submitted by user
            $this->db->where('procedure_id',$this->input->post('record_id'));
            //update that row with the filename of the document uploaded
            $this->db->update('procedure', $filename); 

        }
```

If you look at this screenshot you will see my "edocument" column from 72-76 has values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxDnE.jpg

So is the update function breaking my database?

Thanks

Comment: +1 for great comments in code. That's what comments should be like!

Comment: Thankyou! :) commenting is important to me otherwise I forget what my code does later

Comment: "in my website it is saying there are 70" - What is the SELECT query used that gives you 70 results? The UPDATE itself should not have anything to do with it. That *is* what your question is, correct? You're asking why it only displays 70 records?

Comment: I am using $this->db->count_all('my_table');

Comment: It is saying there are 70 rows in my table but there is 76, why?!! is Codeigniter broken?

Comment: Try printing `$this->db->last_query();` after your call to the model (when updating and retrieving) to see if any weird SQL calls are being made.

Comment: Okay I have found something strange with doing what you requested: Here is the query `UPDATE `procedure` SET `edocument` = 'Bob73.jpg' WHERE `procedure_id` = '73'`

However checking my database through phpmyadmin it is actually row 77 which has that column value of "bob73.jpg" what could this be?

Comment: Im gonna delete and remake my database from backup see if that fixes it.

Comment: Your function looks fine to me. As shaggy pointed out, your auto_increment column might not exactly correspond with the COUNT values CodeIgniter is running.  If you delete rows in your table, the `patient_id` value will still increment based on the last inserted ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that there are 76 rows?
I see in your picture column `patient_id`, I guess it is auto increment (or at least it is linked with patients table that have auto increment primary key).
But if you had run some `DELETE` queries you see only 70 rows, but the auto increment id will start from the last used number (from 76 in your case).
Have you tried running simple `COUNT` query (without using codeigniter active record)? If yes, what was the result?

Comment: 70. I deleted my database and remade it from backup - it is now fixed but I will give you the points as I think your answer may indicate what went wrong with my database, the auto increment.